# Driver for JMicron SD Controller

Tags: sd-card, lspci

I have an Asus laptop running Ubuntu 15.10, it has an internal sd card reader, but I don't seem to be able to use it, the system didn't make anything when inserting a card.
The output of `lspci -nnk` is:

```
07:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2381] (rev 80)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1a07]
07:00.5 Ethernet controller [0200]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [197b:0250] (rev 03)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1905]
Kernel driver in use: jme
```

I tried a couple of solutions out there but none worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same problem of yours, then, after a couple of weeks with no solution, i finally found a website that had my problem solved. Run these commands on the terminal as root:

**~# echo tifm_sd >> /etc/modules

~# echo mmc_block >> /etc/modules**

Idk why but "*sudo*" does not work with me for these commands.

The website that helped me: http://kaustubhghanekar.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/making-you-sd-card-work-with-your.html

That is it! Here my SD Card Reader (JMicron) now works properly.

Ps: Sorry for the bad english, it isn't my natural language.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Nice catch!  The reason `sudo` won't work here is because the `>>` operator is a pipe, and what follows would be run as a normal user.  Since /etc/modules is only writable by root, you need to give the right hand side of the pipe sudo privileges, but to do *that* you need to use a bidirectional pipe.  e.g. `echo tlfm_sd | sudo tee --append /etc/modules`

Comment: Oh, thanks :) I thought that there was only one type of pipe, the `|`. Time has passed and I learned more and more about Unix and it's universe, but I'm still too noob haha